# Signatures in Propostional logic (Hodges and Chiswell Exercise 3.4.4)

Tags: propositional-calculus

The exercise 3.4.4 of Mathematical Logic by Hodges and Chiswell is like that: 
"Let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be signatures with $\rho \subseteq \sigma$ 
(a) Suppose $D$ is a $\sigma$-derivation, and $D'$ is got from $D$ by writing $\perp$ em place of each symbol in $D$ that is in $\sigma$ but not in $\rho$. Show that $D'$ is a $\rho$-derivation.
(b) Suppose $\Gamma$ is a set of formula de $LP(\rho)$ and $\psi$ is a formula of $LP(\rho)$, such that the sequent $(\Gamma \vdash_\sigma \psi)$ is correct. Show that the sequent $(\Gamma \vdash_\rho \psi)$ is correct." 
The solution of part (a) is presented and the solution of part (b) is an application of part (a).
My problem is that I can't imagine in propositional logic **an example** where this exercise is applicable. 
Some help? 
Thanks.

Comment: Induction on the derivation-tree... Unfortunately, many cases to check: try with some significant one. The base case is straightforward: $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ with only the Assumption rule applied: thus $\varphi \in \Gamma$ and thus $\Gamma [\bot/p] \vdash \varphi [\bot/p]$

Comment: Then try some cases for Induction step: $(\lnot \text I)$ and $(\land \text I)$.

Comment: I would like to know if there is only one case where a symbol doesn’t appear in conclusion and undischarged assumptions and appears in the middle of derivation.

Comment: We have the so-called [SUBFORMULA PROPERTY](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/review-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/subformula-property-in-classical-natural-deduction-established-constructively/47716AE48D641D521E342B713391A055)... but it is a "advanced" issue and I'm quite sure that at that point of the book there is no need to consider it for the above exercise.

Comment: Maybe the intuition can help... why the above substitution does not cause troubles? Consider the simple derivation without assumption $\vdash \varphi$. By soundness, we know that $\varphi$ is a tautology; thus, it is always TRUE for every assignment of truth values to the prop symbols. If we replace one of them, say $p$, with $\bot$ we do not "produce" a new case in the corresponding truth table, because this case was already present when $p$ was assigned FALSE. This amounts to (prove by Induction) that if $\vDash \varphi$, then $\vDash \varphi [\bot/p]$.

Comment: In propositional logic.

Comment: But then, by Completeness: $\vdash \varphi [\bot/p]$. This "semi-formal" argument can be reframed without Soundness-Completeness but still using Induction.

Comment: Thanks, Mauro. But I am not worried about the solution of the problem. The solution of part (a) is presented in the book, and the solution of part (b) is an application of part (a). I wanted a concrete example of these conditions in propositional logic without excessive use of RAA.

Comment: An example of that kind of derivation? $p[\bot/p] \vdash (p \lor q)[\bot/p]$

Comment: I will give you an useless example, but I can't write here. I will answer my own question.

Comment: But I think this is the issue. Extra symbols cannot play an important role, otherwise it would not be possible to replace them with $\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following derivation:

$
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{\dfrac{p \quad [\neg p]}{\perp}}{q}
\quad
  \dfrac{\dfrac{p \quad [\neg p]}{\perp}}{\neg q}
}
{\perp}
}
{p}
$

This proves the sequent $\{p\} \vdash p$. The derivation uses $q$ and this symbol doesn't appear in the conclusion or in the undischarged assumption.

Replacing $q$ by $\perp$:

$
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{\dfrac{p \quad [\neg p]}{\perp}}{\perp}
\quad
  \dfrac{\dfrac{p \quad [\neg p]}{\perp}}{\neg \perp}
}
{\perp}
}
{p}
$

But it is an useless example. I would like to know if there is a more useful derivation with these conditions.

Comment: You have to replace a prop symbol with $\bot$... Thus, assume that $\phi$ is $p$ and replace it with $\bot$. Can you check the new derivation?

Comment: But you can also assume that $\psi$ is $q$ and replace it with 4\bit$. Check it again...

Comment: The gist is... not so much the result, but the proof technique: induction on the derivation tree.

Comment: Regarding the exercise, I think I have to replace $\psi$ with $\perp$.

Comment: Yes... the text says: "writing $\bot$ in place of each symbol in D that is in σ but not in ρ.." So we have to use symbols: $p,q,\ldots$ and not schematic (meta-)variables. So my example is: assume you have used $q$ (which is in $\sigma$ but **not** in signature $\rho$) and replace it with $\bot$. The result is in "rho-language" and - the theorem says - is still a good derivation.

Comment: Yes, I used metavariables like symbols of the signatures. Thank you.

Comment: Answer edited. Thank you.